# How to access normal java objects in FTL?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Spring 4 with Freemarker Template. I have a helper class whose methods I want to access in my FTL template file. I don't want to pass it as a model. How can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to add it as (to) the model? Where have you created instances of the class?

Comment: Simply beacuse it's not a model, it is just a helper class. I have created its instances in other classes where its methods are needed. I just want to know apart from using it as a model, what are the other ways of accessing a java object in FTL?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this, it can help you to pass a helper class: http://www.javawebdevelop.com/1389653/

```
  // ftl  
  public static TemplateHashModel useStaticPackage(String packageName)  
  {  
    try  
    {  
      BeansWrapper wrapper = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance();  
      TemplateHashModel staticModels = wrapper.getStaticModels();  
      TemplateHashModel fileStatics = (TemplateHashModel) staticModels.get(packageName);  
      return fileStatics;  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
       e.printStackTrace();    
    }  
  }  

//   

//data.put("list", list);  
data.put("Helper",useStaticPackage("com.test.Helper"));  

// ftl   
${Helper.method()}
```

Comment: `BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance()` is deprecated, and anyway one should use the actual `ObjectWrapper` of the `Configuration`. (See in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `TemplateModel` variable, but you can add it globally (that is, only once, during application initialization), where you configure FreeMarker:

```
// Do these AFTER the cfg is ready otherwise: 

ObjectWrapper ow = cfg.getObjectWrapper();
// ow will be usually a DefaultObjectWrapper, which is a subclass of BeansWrapper
if (!(ow instanceof BeansWrapper)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("The objet wrapper must implement " + BeansWrapper.class.getName() + " in this application.");
}
cfg.setSharedVariable("mu", ((BeansWrapper) ow).getStaticModels().get(MyUtils.class.getName()));
```

where `MyUtils` could be something like

```
public class MyUtils {

    public static String foo(String s) {
        return "foo " + s;
    }

    // ... further methods here

}
```

and then in all templates you can do this:

```
${mu.foo('bar')};
```

You could also add the result of `getStaticModels()` itself as shared variable, say, with name `classes`, and then in the template you could do `${classes['com.example.MyUtils'].foo('bar')}`, but it's IMO too technical for a template.